# JAVA_HOME setting doesn't show up in Workspace Settings to complete W3C Validation Extension Installation

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, w3c-validation, java-home, vssettings

I followed all the steps to install the W3C Validation Extension.
I have the `JAVA_HOME` variable in my Environment Variables with value of `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1` to which I appended `;%JAVA_HOME%\bin` as required.

Then I went to the User Settings of the extension in VS Code and I changed the value of the Java Home setting in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1`. But when I headed over to the Workspace Settings of the extension, I found *no Java home setting*.

*It's missing*, so I can't change the value.

Of course, this causes VS Code to alert me that the Java runtime could not be located.

Anyone has any idea why?

Comment: I've watched the [**W3C Validation** installation tutorial](https://github.com/Umoxfo/vscode-w3cvalidation#set-the-java_home-environment-variable), the point is adding java to PATH, which is often finished after installing the java. Can you tell me why you set java.home in workspace setting again after you've finished it in User setting?

Comment: Bacause after some resarch on the web I gathered that is best to put the path in both of 'em. But I don't have the option to put it in the Workspace Settings, that's because I'm missing the setting itself, that's why I opened this thread. Plus, since I can't set it in the Workspace setting I'm missing the value there. And it doesn't work without putting it in there, which suggests to me that i's necessary.
Regarding your first question, I simply followed the instruction that comes with the w3c validation plug-in.

Comment: Well, I tryied uninstall vscode and reinstall it. Always works, idk. Thanks anyway!

Comment: That‘s great, happy coding:)